# why laravel 5.6 returns file does not exist error?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I putted file on `project-dir/client_secret_1***.apps.googleusercontent.com.json` and then added variable into env file.

```
GOOGLE_PLAY_CREDENTIAL=http://local.project-dir/client_secret_1***.apps.googleusercontent.com.json
```

and then in `config/services.php`

```
return [

    'google_play' => [
        'credential' => env('GOOGLE_PLAY_CREDENTIAL'),
    ],

];
```

So now when I use it as like below

```
$client->setAuthConfig(config('services.google_play.credential'));
```

it is returning error which is

```
"file "http://local.project-dir/client_secret_1***.apps.googleusercontent.com.json" does not exist"
```

Can someone kindly guide me, where I am wrong so that I can fix the issue. I would like to appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: put client_secret_1***.apps.googleusercontent.com.json in side your public folder, Example: project-dir/public/client_secret_1***.apps.googleusercontent.com.json

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel [Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem).

1. Edit ***config/filesystems.php*** to create new disk:

```php
'services' => [
      'driver' => 'local',
      'root' => storage_path('app/services'),
],
// ...
```

2. Put your .json file into `%your_project_root%/storage/app/services/`
3. Edit .env file:

```php
GOOGLE_PLAY_CREDENTIAL=client_secret_1***.apps.googleusercontent.com.json
```

4. Change setAuthConfig param:

```php
$client->setAuthConfig(Storage::disk('services')->get(config('services.google_play.credential')));
```

Test your storage using Tinker in console:

```php
php artisan tinker

Storage::disk('services')->get(config('services.google_play.credential'));
```